# Django+Nginx reverse proxy apache

Tags: python, django, apache, nginx, reverse-proxy

So I have 2 machines what I am planning is to have Django+nginx on one machine
and then use a reverse proxy apache as the front end on another machine

Does that make sense? I am new to webhost stuff.

I am having trouble finding answers. any direction would be helpful

Comment: security.   But how would do it? just django apache on 2 machines? but I cant figure out how to do that

Comment: Please don't open multiple questions about the same thing.